# How to print to pdf multiple sheets for tableau workbook saved in a local drive programatically

Tags: tableau-api

I have a tableau workbook saved in my local drive and i manually open the workbook and select multiple sheets from it and print the sheets as pdf from file menu. I want to automate that task. checked tabcmd but it only works with tableau server.

Comment: One person has made a video on how to do this using AutoIt. check it out here. https://dwuconsulting.com/tools/software-videos/automating-tableau-pdf

Comment: Thanks Bernardo, but is there any other way apart from autoit. The problem with autoit is if the user moves the mouse pointer then the entire code goes for a toss. so i thought of using tabcmd but i after googling i cant find anyway to use tabcmd to control published tableau workbook.

Comment: Not that am aware of. Like you said, tabcmd is only for server.